# Get product weight unit in phtml file

Tags: magento2, configuration, product-weight

I have a phtml file that needs to load the weight unit of the product, the weight unit is from the store configuration, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

For product weight unit. Try this -

You need to use the instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in your block:

Create the method `getWeightUnit()`

```
public function getWeightUnit()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/locale/weight_unit',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

and call in your template `echo $this->getWeightUnit();`

Comment: .how to get the width unit in magento2 ....

Comment: Thanks! Tried this one and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the product loaded inside your custom phtml file, you can use:

```
$weight = $product->getData('weight');
```